# Eporting simple java application

Tags: java, eclipse, export

I'd like to know whether I can export a simple app that just prints a sentence on the screen with eclipse?

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "export"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible. Within Eclipse navigate to File > Export > Runnable JAR file. (most common)

An alternative way of doing it is to have a .bat file call the .java file.